# Navision 2013 dynamically change caption of field list on page

Tags: dynamics-nav

In the page I have a list of fields where I can make a filter.
Typically it reflects the caption field. The list Is subject to the field property 'captionclass'  (e.g. Dimension)
I modified codeunit 42 to manage (with my function) the caption dependent on a value in a record in a table. It works fine on OpenPage however if I change records in the Page List it will not be reinitialized.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Does using the following code to refresh the form when necessary, resolve the issue?

**Form**

```
CurrForm.UPDATE(FALSE);
```

**Page**

```
CurrPage.UPDATE(FALSE);
```

Comment: No, thanks. anyhow for page is better CurrPage.ACTIVATE(TRUE).

Comment: Ah, I missed your references to pages -- CurrPage.UPDATE will still function. If CurrPage.ACTIVATE works then all good :)